# Facebook Graph Explorer: Finding messages between 2 friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On Facebook, when you visit a friend's page, you can view the messages between both of you by clicking on the 'Message' button and selecting 'See Friendship' option.

I want to find these same messages using the Facebook's Graph Explorer. I know this is possible but not able to identify the options.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is **not possible** programmatically via FB's graph explorer. It's only possible on the website.